# stop script warning in firefox on load of directive in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, user-experience

I have a select All functionality into my application. where i have minimum 100 items in loop to select. i am getting every item and add into separate $rootScope variable which is used in ng-repeat on li element. in this element i also added "mydirective" to perform some render. this will generate Stop script issue on Firefox.

In directive rendering perform through $timeout. but still issue occur. please help me on this.following are my directive

```
app.directive('addToCartDirective', function ($timeout, $rootScope) {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    $timeout(function () {
        var params = scope.$eval(attrs.addToCartDirective);
       global.leftBarAddClassicIdeal(params['size'], params['product'], params['id'],$rootScope,params['index']);           
    },100);
};
```

});

**HTML**

```
<ul class="left-menu1"  id="ul_left_bar_ideal_0"  >
  <li add-to-cart-directive="{size:'{{key}}',index:'{{$index}}',product:'Ideal',id:'li_left_bar_ideal_{{$index}}'}" style="width: 100px; height: 120px;min-height:120px" class='left-bar' data-ng-repeat="idealImage in currentCart" id='li_left_bar_ideal_{{$index}}'  ng-if="idealImage.imgSize == key">
   <div class='img_container'>
       <a  data-ng-click="_appService.displayDetailView(idealImage.imgName,null,'Ideal',key);" data-current-size="{{key}}" href ><img data-custom-width='' data-custom-height=''  class='pic' style='display:none;' ng-src="{{idealImage.imgPath}}" width="90" height="70">
          <div class="product_thumb" style="background-image: url('{{idealImage.imgPath}}');display: none;"></div></a>
          </div>
         <span class='left_img_ind_count'><b class="badge-count-small badge">{{idealImage.imgQuan}}</b></span></li> </ul>
```

**Directive Method**

```
global.leftBarAddClassicIdeal = function (size, product_type, li_id,_rootScope,_index) {
//console.log(size, product_type, li_id);
console.log(_rootScope.imgList,"IMGS")
var product_type = product_type;
var product_size = size;

//var li_width = '100'
//var li_height = '120';
var product_data = [];
product_data['frame_width'] = cart_sizes[product_type.toLowerCase()].inner_width;
product_data['frame_height'] = cart_sizes[product_type.toLowerCase()].inner_width;

product_data['product_type'] = product_type;
product_data['product_size'] = product_size;
product_data['container_l_margin_top'] = 30;
 angular.element('#' + li_id).css({width: cart_sizes[product_type.toLowerCase()].outer_width, height: cart_sizes[product_type.toLowerCase()].outer_height});

    var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
    product_data['li_id'] = li_id;       
    product_data['pic_real_width'] = _rootScope.currentCart[product_type].data[_index].imgWidth;
    product_data['pic_real_height'] = _rootScope.currentCart[product_type].data[_index].imgHeight;
    global.setProductLayout(product_data, 'home',_rootScope);
  }
```

**Note** : this is basically show image thumbs and scale with directive.

Comment: well, let's see, you loop through 100 items, and for each item, you add a directive which has a timeout of 100 miliseconds, so you are essentially adding 10 seconds worth of timeouts to your processing.  Why wouldn't Firefox warn you about a long running script?

Comment: what's the purpose of a $timeout in this context, anyway?

Comment: two purpose. 1 - element has to added into html(otherwise directive not applied on element) , 2- I tried to queue processing after set time of interval to avoid these stop script issue

Comment: first, I'm not sure what $timeout has to do with adding things to the HTML, and second, $timeout isn't going to "queue" processing, it's only going to make the script take longer.  Perhaps you could show the entire process, and not just this directive bit, if the script error was occurring before the $timeout was added...

Comment: I edit my question and provide html element on which directive added , directive method.

Comment: so you are calling `$eval` 100 times? have you considered using an isolate scope and setting those values as parameters that don't need to be evaluated?

Comment: Yes I am calling $eval for getting element passed parameter and use those for rendering into leftBarAddClassicIdeal() . not understand what you want to ask in 2nd question.

Comment: I'm suggesting that instead of using `$eval`, you pass the variables directly in to the directive.

Comment: I did pass variable directly except $eval. but still same problem. basically issue is regarding digest cycle in loop